# Activating and Deactivating Constraints Not Updating View Frame

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a subview that contains a Label and a Button, however, the button is not always needed. If the Button is needed, the Label needs to be displayed at the top and the button at the bottom of the view. If the Button is not needed, the Label needs to be displayed in the middle of the view.

To accomplish this, I have three constraints I modify:

1. Label bottom to Button top equals 0. (Constraint1)
2. Label bottom to Button top greater than or equal to 0 (Constraint3)
3. Button Height (Constraint3)

NOTE: The Label has a top constraint with the view set to 0 and the Button has a bottom constraint with the view set to 0. These go unchanged.

NOTE: All constraints are set to be installed and the button height is 42 at build time

If the Button is needed, Constraint1 gets uninstalled and Constraint3 gets set to 42.

[image]

If the Button is not needed, Constraint1 gets installed and Constraint3 gets set to 0.

[image]

As you can see, this works on the storyboard as expected. However, in code, the behavior is not reflected. If the button is needed, I try this:

```
constraint3.constant = 42
self.view.removeConstraint(constraint1)
self.view.updateConstraints
```

But instead of the expected result, I get a result as if the constraint was never removed:

[image]

I uninstall the constraint in storyboard and it looks correct, but when I uninstall the constraint in code, it doesn't... What is incorrect/missing from my code to get this working properly?

Comment: Do you want the Height of the view to be constant? Or should the view height change if the button is not needed?

Comment: the view's height is constant.

Comment: OK - and are you removing the button from the  view? And do you want the label vertically centered? Or do you want it to fill the view's height?

Comment: and... a little confusing... Is your 3rd Image how you *want* it to look when the button is needed, and your 2nd image how you want it to look *without* the button? So your first image is not a "final result" for either condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
self.view.removeConstraint(constraint1)
```

to

```
parentView.removeConstraint(constraint1)
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This constraint need to be removed from the parent view of both the label and the button which contains that constraint

Comment: `self.view` is in reference to the ViewController's view, not the subview that the button and label are nested in.

Comment: hook the parentView as outlet and remove the constraint from it

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Any knowledge of why I am unable to just utilize the isActive Boolean to adjust this? i.e `constraint1.isActive = false`

Comment: you can set this property only once , then changing it will result in a crash as the constraint is invalidated

Comment: the height of the button is a constraint that is hooked to an IBOutlet, but thanks for the warning. And thanks for the information!

Comment: If you want to toggle a constraint on and off, instead of changing isActive, set the constraints to high and low priorities. They will both be "active" but the one with the high priority is what will be displayed on screen.

Comment: @Sh_Khan You can toggle `isActive` as much as you want. It will result in crash only if your constraint variable is `weak` because setting a constraint's `isActive = false` removes that constraint from view so there is no strong reference for that IBOutlet and it becomes nil. Just remove the weak keyword it will work like a charm.

Comment: @JakeG You cannot change constraint priority at runtime but you can toggle `isActive` as many times as you want so changing priority is just a use case not replacement.

Comment: @crysis That is incorrect. You can change constraint priority at runtime. You just cant change from Required to a lower priority.

Comment: @JakeG From apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526946-priority):
`Priorities may not change from nonrequired to required, or from required to nonrequired. An exception will be thrown if a priority of required in macOS or UILayoutPriorityRequired in iOS is changed to a lower priority, or if a lower priority is changed to a required priority after the constraints is added to a view. Changing from one optional priority to another optional priority is allowed even after the constraint is installed on a view.`

Comment: @crysis That is exactly what I said. You can not change from required to lower, but `changing from one optional priority to another optional priority is allowed`. If you have a weak reference to the constraints because you're using storyboard, instead of changing isActive and losing the reference, you can toggle between `NSLayoutPriority.defaultHigh` and `NSLayoutPriority.defaultLow` to determine which constraint should be used.

Comment: @JakeG Dude you can only change from one `optional to another optional priority` not from `required to optional`. There is a difference. It implies that if a constraint is being used to build your interface then it's priority cannot be changed. You can only remove this constraint so that optional constraint can come in play.

Comment: @crysis Again, I don't know why you think you are correct in saying `It implies that if a constraint is being used to build your interface then it's priority cannot be changed.`